# Multiply a decimal number in vim by a fixed amount

Tags: regex, awk, vim, text-processing

I have a file with the following contents:

```
set x 0.00456 y 0.05896.
```

I want to multiply the digits by a fixed amount (lets say 1000). The numbers do not always exist in the same column so anything with awk is out of the picture. I have been trying this but not sure if the way I am using submatch is correct.

```
%s/ \d*\.\d*/\=submatch(2)*100
```

Answer (score 6):

### vim

Your `submatch(2)` usage is not correct. You don't have any matching groups, so you should use `submatch(0)`.

Another problem in your codes is, you should first change the string into float, then do the calculation:

```
%s/\v\d+[.]\d+/\=str2float(submatch(0))*1000/g
```

## awk

> The numbers do not always exist in the same column so anything with
>   awk is out of the picture.

This is not true. You can check each column, if it matches the number format, you do the math calculation:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/[0-9]+[.][0-9]+/)$i*=1000}7' file
```

You can also call the awk within your vim:

```
%!awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/[0-9]+[.][0-9]+/)$i*=1000}7'
```